# Sort a dictionary by key if the key exists, if it doesn't put it to the end of the list

Tags: python, python-2.7

Been scratching my head on how to accomplish this,

```
sorted_dict = sorted(dict['values'],
                    key=lambda k: k['a']['b'])
```

Now in this dict some values of a have a b value, while some don't. I want it to sort by b values and if it doesn't exist, just put it at the back of the list. Is there anyway to do without some complex code such as splitting the values of a for those that have a b value and those that don't?

Answer (score 3):

Nope.

```
key=lambda k: ('b' not in k['a'], k['a'].get('b', None))
```

Comment: In p3 some things have changed.  I'm curious why your sort works in p3, but if you sort the tuples produced by the key function directly: `print(sorted ([(False, 1),       (True, None), (False, None)]))` it produces the expected error: `TypeError: unorderable types: NoneType() < int()`

Comment: You don't need `None` in `k['a'].get('b', None)`. The default return value for `.get()` is already `None`.

Comment: I should add, I used this data: `my_list = [
    {
        'a': {'b': 1}
    },
    {
        'a': {'c': 2}
    },
    {   
        'a': {'b': 0}
    }
]`